# Adjective for two effects of the same cause

Tags: adjectives

Is there an adjective describing two events being effects of the same cause? For example, if *A*, *B* and *C* are events, such that *A* causes both *B* and *C*, I would like to state something along the lines of:

*B* and *C* are ADJECTIVE

or

The relation between *B* and *C* is ADJECTIVE

Comment: _Concomitant_ may be as close as you can get, conflating its _attendant_ {[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concomitant)} and _existing or occurring together; associative_ {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concomitant)} senses.

Comment: "Of common origin" would be an appropriate phrase for some contexts.

Comment: They are both *results*, or *consequences*, of A. There's nothing more you can say, unless the relations are such that they share something else. B and C can be entirely unrelated, beyond both resulting from A.

Comment: I guess you're looking for more than 'connected', 'related', 'intertwined,or 'interelated'?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see using the hyphen and the,ed, can help with that so you can say (mutual-caused events) in order to say that both of the events share the same cause. For example blue-eyed girl or broken-hearted kid

Comment: Do you have any references for *mutual-caused events* with that meaning? That phrase sounds like it would mean *events that cause each other*. Also, what does "the,ed," (*sic*) mean?

Answer (score 1):

*B* and *C* are ***congenetic***.

Collins:

> **[congenetic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/congenetic)**
>   *adjective*
>
> having a common or similar origin
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Also, *B* and *C* are ***congeneric***.

ODO:

> **[congeneric](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/congeneric)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Of a related nature or origin.
>   ‘the two sets were congeneric’

Answer (score 0):

Cogenerated, unless that's too specific

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogeneration